# Python converting recursive permutation function to iterative

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I have an unknown number of Integer variables say that can range from [0,9]
I want to iterate over all permutations of these values.

If the number of variables was constant, it would be easy to write nested for loops.  I came up with a recursive function that does what I want, but was curious if there was a way to do it iteratively.

```
def nested(array,index):
    n = len(array)
    for i in range(10):
        array[n-index]=i
        #len(array-1) end of array
        if(index == 1):
            print(array)
            #do something later
        else:
            nested(array,index-1)

#generate all permutations, change n to change size of list.            
n = 4
array = [0]*n
nested(array,len(array))
```

I tried using the so called "Simple Method" found here -> http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html
But I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Please be more specific in what didn't work in the blog that you have linked. As far as I can see, the post covers iteration to recursion well, please update the question with your effort.

Comment: There's no real "secret" here. Most of what is explained in that blog post applies to linear recursive algorithms (search for an item in a linked list), as opposed to branching recursive algorithms (search for a path in a graph). The permutations problem is the latter (a tree). The easiest way to convert a recursive algorithm of this form to an iterative version is to use a stack / queue data structure. Pop an element from the stack. Operate on it. Push the branch nodes on it. Quit when the stack is empty.

Comment: ... for example, compare the recursive and iterative psuedocode for Depth First Search from here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned by another commenter, the key is to simulate your tail recursion using a stack.

Take note I `append()` a tuple of `(array, index)` into the `stack`, which mirrors the call to recursive function in your original recursive solution. At the start of the iteration, it does `stack.pop()`, which mimics the body of your recursive function. Recursive call becomes `stack.append()`.

```
def nested(array):
    stack = []
    n = len(array)
    stack.append((array.copy(), n))
    while(stack):
        array, index = stack.pop()        
        for i in range(10):
            array[n-index]=i
            #len(array-1) end of array
            if(index == 1):
                print(array)
                #do something later
            else:
                stack.append((array.copy(), index-1)) 

#generate all permutations, change n to change size of list.            
n = 4
array = [0]*n
nested(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). There is a Class "permutations" that could solve your problem perfectly.